# Stokes flow between 2 spheres

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

The problem is given like this:

> Given two rotating spheres with constant angular velocity $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ around the vertical axis and pressure on the borders of spheres is $p_1$ and $p_2$ ,filled with fluid between them, using Navier-Stokes equations, find the physical velocity components in spherical coordinates (no gravity, no slip condition).
>
> Assume (${v_r} = 0,\quad {v_\theta } = 0,\quad {v_\varphi } = f(r)\sin
> > \theta$)

It's a Stokes flow problem, and I need to find the function $f(r)$. The equations I derived look like this:

\begin{align}
\frac{{\partial p}}{{\partial r}} &= {\rho _0}\sin^{2}\left( \theta  \right)\frac{{{f^2}\left( r \right)}}{r}\tag{1}\\
\frac{{\partial p}}{{\partial \theta }} &= 0\tag{2}\\
\frac{{\partial p}}{{\partial \varphi }} &= \, - \mu \sin\left( \theta  \right)\frac{{\left( { - 2f\left( r \right) + {r^2}f''\left( r \right)} \right)}}{r}\tag{3}
\end{align}

I have no idea how to solve this. Is there any extra equations I can use to find $f(r)$? When I searched for Stokes flow around a sphere, I keep finding examples where the ${v_r},{v_\theta }$ is something given in form of a steam function but ${v_\varphi }$ is zero.

Comment: Why don't the examples where $v_r = v_\theta = 0$ help you? Those are the same assumptions you have listed in your question...

Comment: in the examples they are not zero,but the $vφ$ is zero so i have a reversed situation

Comment: Could you provide a schematic drawing for the problem? From your description, it's difficult to see how the spheres are located w.r.t. each other.

Comment: @Deep You have 2 concentric spheres of different radii rotating about a common axis passing through their centers.  There is a viscous liquid filling the space between the spheres.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I see now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't confirm your 2nd and 3rd equations.  I get:

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta}=\rho f^2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}$$
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial \phi}=\frac{\mu \sin^2{\theta}}{r}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)-2f\right]$$
By symmetry, p is not a function of $\phi$.  Therefore, 
$$\frac{d}{d r}\left(r^2\frac{d f}{d r}\right)-2f=0$$

This is a Stokes (low Reynolds number) flow, and the radial- and latitudinal equations contain only inertial terms.  So they can be neglected.  The only relevant equation is the one in the $\phi$ direction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a look into "Analytical investigation of the compressible navier-stokes-equations for
low mach- and reynolds-numbers" by Michael Viehl from 1989. It should help.
Best wishes
Michael Viehl

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/404908)